# Union A List of Lists Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

This isn't that complicated of a question, but I can't wrap my head around it in linq.

I have an `Enumerable<T>` containing an `Enumerable<string>`:

```
public class
{
   List<List<string>> ListOfLists = new List<List<string>>();
}
```

I basically want to return each unique string from ListOfLists; this is easy using a foreach loop and a storage variable (I could probably improve the efficiency of not having the distinct at the very end, but that's not the point):

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (var v in ListOfLists)
{
   foreach (var s in v)
   {
      result.Add(s);
   }
}

result.Distinct();
```

How do I do this with linq?

Comment: You already have the answers. I would suggest taking a shot at Extension method with this problem! Where your extension methods does the SelectMany and Distinct in an optimised way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx

Answer (score 13):

```
var distinctStrings = ListOfLists.SelectMany(list => list).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, the query expression syntax is sometimes easier (I find) to come up with than the correct invocation of `SelectMany`. Here it would be:

```
result = (from list in ListOfLists
          from s in list
          select s).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = ListOfLists.SelectMany(v => v).ToList().Distinct();
```

EDIT: For better performance, use:

```
var result = ListOfLists.SelectMany(v => v).Distinct();
```

or

```
var result = ListOfLists.SelectMany(v => v).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: No need for that ToList in the middle

Comment: And if you did need the ToList, do it after the Distinct rather than before. In this case, your Distinct is now returning an IEnumerable<T> which may not be what you wanted. Also, there is a memory/perf hit to doing ToList on the entire list and then restricting the results to Distinct rather than doing Distinct first.

Comment: @Jim Wooley - great suggestion.  Thanks to you and RichK for the feedback.  We already learn.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! - 
I have "Intersect" A List of Lists Using Linq - 
var result = ListOfLists.SelectMany(v => v).Where(m => ListOfLists.TrueForAll(n => n.Contains(m))).Distinct().ToList();