# How to reduce dimension?

Tags: vb.net, linq, ienumerable

Let us consider that I have an `IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Integer))`. All the inner `IEnumerable`s contain `IDs`. I would like to gather all the `IDs` `Distinctl`y into an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)`. I can do that if I do something like this:

```
Dim result as New List(Of Integer)
For Each element In IDs
    result.AddRange(element)
Next
result = result.Distinct
```

I have two problems with this approach:
- I have to write the iteration code when there is probably a `Function` for this purpose that I am unaware of
- The result is a `List` and I would like to keep the class of the inner `IEnumerable`

Is there a handy LINQ way to do this?

EDIT:

This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328233/union-a-list-of-lists-using-linq), since I am speaking about `IEnumerable`s, not `List`s. Yes, I am aware that every `List` is an `IEnumerable`, but I am also aware that not every `IEnumerable` is a `List`. As a result, this is a more general question than the one which was marked as duplicate, as I have specified in my original question that I would like to maintain the `Class` of the inner `IEnumerable` in the result. If it was an array, I prefer to use an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Union A List of Lists Using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328233/union-a-list-of-lists-using-linq)

Comment: A `List` is an `IEnumerable`

Comment: @KeithMifsud, I am asking about IEnumerables. If they were arrays, I would like the result to be array as well. This is a more general question.

Comment: @Sehnsucht, yes, but an IEnumerable is not necessarily a List. I want this to be applicable to arrays of arrays as well.

Comment: Hey I'm just trying to keep SO clean. The question is a duplicate and so is the answer. You want `IEnumerable` and the old question was a `List' which is an 'Ienumerabe` so the solutions works exactly the same

Comment: @KeithMifsud, I understand your concern, but you must understand that your understanding is flawed. Not every IEnumerable is a List. There are IEnumerables that are not Lists. For instance, arrays. Since arrays are not Lists and Lists are not array, you are incorrect when you state that IEnumerable is List. The solution to the other question is incorrect here, unless SelectMany returns an instance of the same class (not interface) the inner lists were. Here we have the problem of possibly different types of inner IEnumerables.

Comment: @KeithMifsud, also, I will conduct experiments with SelectMany, but even if it is the solution to this question as well, this question is different. If the same answer would mean that the question is the same. We should not mix the possible equivalence of answers with the meaning of the question. If my name Árpád? Yes. Am I male? Yes. So, we have the same answer for two different questions. Are they the same? Am I doing the same thing when I am asking your gender as when I am asking your name? Off course not.

Comment: @KeithMifsud, let us consider the example when I create a custom Class which Implements IEnumerable. If I am using that Class as the inner IEnumerables, then we have the question whether SelectMany will result in an instance of that Class. That is an experiment to be done. Also, If I have two elements, an instance of an array and an instance of my custom class, what will the result be? A List? An array? An instance of my custom class? We should never say that an IEnumerable is a List, but we should always say that a List is an IEnumerable, therefore, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: If you need information about `SelectMany` read the MSDN however you asked for a LINQ extension and that is it

Comment: @KeithMifsud, the question was not about SelectMany. It was a suggestion and some further questions were raised to see whether it fulfills the criteria which was already present in the original question. There was no answer to those further questions up until now and if there will be no answers to those before I finish the things I am working on, then I will conduct a few experiments and will come with the information which results from those.

Comment: With the edit I finally understand the question (that bit about *class of inner*. Simply put, you can't ; I can pass an `IEnumerable(Of (IReadOnlyCollection(Of T))` ; I can pass an `IEnumerable(Of MyCustomThing)` with MyCustomThing Implementing IEnumerable. How should that method would know how to add items to them. You still can defer the "shape" of the result to the caller (up to him to transform the result in what he wants) or use overloads to leverage those "transformation" for him (for the "known" cases)

Comment: @Sehnsucht, so, if we want to keep the inner class as the result, then we have to create a wrapper to SelectMany which will convert the resultin IEnumerable to the desired class (for instance MyCustomThing)?

Comment: If you want something more specific than IEnumerable you'll have to do the "conversion" yourself (that's why there is `ToArray` and `ToList` in Linq ; if  there was a magical thing which allowed the returned type to be "flexible" they probably would have used it ; that's the same kind of logic as the numerous overload of Min/Max in Linq for various numeric types)

Comment: @Sehnsucht, then a wrapper function could be useful, which would check for the class and convert the return to that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SelectMany` extension method to flatten the structure, once flatten look for `Distinct`

```
result = IDs.SelectMany(Function(x) x).Distinct();
```

check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Raany6)

Comment: Hari, can you confirm that SelectMany will result in an instance of the class used in the inner IEnumerables?

Comment: It does, @LajosArpad .